# Failed to set remote answer sdp: A BUNDLE group contains a MID='' matching no m= section

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi, webrtc

I am trying to send video from raspberry pi to website using WebRTC. raspberrypi side using libary aiortc in python create answer and send to website but i got this error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: A BUNDLE group contains a MID='' matching no m= section.".

I do not understand what the problem is.

This is the process

web create offer --> web setlocaldecription(offer) and send to raspberry pi --> raspberry pi get offer from web and setRemotedecription(offer) --> raspberry create answer and setlocaldescription(answer) --> send answer to website --> website get answer and setRemoteDescription(I got this error)

my website create offer and send to raspberry pi
offer `sdp:"v=0\r\no=- 7829234644314238351 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\n" type:"offer"`

raspberry pi creates answer

answer `sdp:"v=0\r\no=- 3882080493 3882080493 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE \r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\n" type:"answer"`

In my case. I try set bundlePolicy is 'balanced' and sdpSementics is 'plan-b' on website but rapberry pi havne't set.

```
const iceConfiguration = 
  {
    bundlePolicy: 'balanced',
    sdpSemantics:'plan-b',
    iceServers: [
        {
            urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }
    ]
  }

//peerconnect STUN and TURN server
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);
```

but I get the same error. I expect that the programme can `setRemotedescription(answer)` and send video and audio from raspberry pi to website.

Comment: Add the entire SDP hidding your ip, so we can help you. 
The location of the error in also unclear , it's in setRemoteDescritpion in the browser ?